# Html.DropDownListFor binding for complex child object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code (ASP.NET MVC/C#)...simplifying some for brevity.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CitySelectList { get; set; }
}

public class AddressViewModel
{
   public int AddressId { get; set; }
   public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
   public int CityId { get; set; }
}
```

In the razor view I have the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Address.CityId, Model.CitySelectList)
```

The right city is selected in the dropdown at load time (ie...the original value) so that works fine, but when I submit the form, the CityId property is not updated with the newly selected value....it still contains the original city's id.

I added a new property to the UserViewModel called "SelectedCityId" and bound that to the dropdownlist like this to test the complex nested object being the problem:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCityId, Model.CitySelectList)
```

When I submit the form using this method, the SelectedCityId does contain the right id so I can see model binding working properly when the object is a simple object, but not when it's a nested child object.

Just for troubleshooting, I checked the postal code field as it also binds to a child property of the Address class, but it does bind properly when using the similar TextBoxFor helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address.PostalCode)
```

So, my question is why does model binding not seem to work with the DropDownListFor helper when the expression ties the control to a nested child property?  I'm sure its something trivial that I am missing, but I'm not seeing what it is and haven't found a similar answer here.

EDIT:
Here is the entire html form from the cshtml file

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyProfile", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myProfileForm" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AddressId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Address.CityId)

            <article class="mysettings">
                <h1>Personal details</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>


                <th>E-mail:</th>
                    <td>@Model.Username
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field3">
                            <label for="new_email">New Email:</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { id = "new_email" })
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit3"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>First name:</th>
                    <td>@Model.FirstName
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field1">
                            <label for="new_name">New First Name:</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { id = "new_name" })
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit1"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#field1" class="gradient-button edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Last name:</th>
                    <td>@Model.LastName
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field2">
                            <label for="new_last_name">New Last Name:</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { id = "new_last_name" })
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit2"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#field2" class="gradient-button edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Display name:</th>
                    <td>@Model.DisplayName
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field_display">
                            <label for="new_display_name">New Display Name:</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DisplayName, new { id = "new_display_name" })
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit_display"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#field_display" class="gradient-button edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Password:</th>
                    <td><input type="password" value="@Model.Membership.Password" disabled="disabled" style="border: none; background-color: white; padding: 0;" />
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field4">
                            <label for="new_password">New Password:</label>
                            @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Membership.Password, new { id = "new_password" })
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit4"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cell phone:</th>
                    <td>@Model.CellPhone
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field_cell">
                            <label for="new_cell">New Cell Phone:</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CellPhone, new { id = "new_cell" })
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit_cell"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#field_cell" class="gradient-button edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Home phone:</th>
                    <td>@Model.HomePhone
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field_home">
                            <label for="new_home">New Home Phone:</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.HomePhone, new { id = "new_home" })
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit_home"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#field_home" class="gradient-button edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Street Address:</th>
                    <td>@(Model.Address != null ? Model.Address.Address1 : "No address given")
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field5">
                            <label for="new_address">New Address:</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address.Address1, new { id = "new_address" })
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit5"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#field5" class="gradient-button edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Town / City:</th>
                    <td>@(Model.Address != null ? Model.Address.City.Name : "No address given")
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field6">
                            <label for="new_city">New City:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Address.CityId, Model.CitySelectList, new { @class = "f-item" })
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit6"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#field6" class="gradient-button edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Postal Code:</th>
                    <td>@(Model.Address != null ? Model.Address.PostalCode : "No address given")
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field7">
                            <label for="new_zip">New Postal Code:</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address.PostalCode, new { id = "new_zip" })
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit7"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#field7" class="gradient-button edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>First Admin Division (State):</th>
                    <td>@(Model.Address != null ? Model.Address.City.FirstAdminDivision.Name : "No address given")
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field8">
                            <label for="new_state">New First Admin Division (State):</label>
                            <input type="text" id="new_state"/>
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit8"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#field8" class="gradient-button edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Country:</th>
                    <td>@(Model.Address != null ? Model.Address.City.FirstAdminDivision.Country.Name : "No address given")
                        <!--edit fields-->
                        <div class="edit_field" id="field9">
                            <label for="new_country">New Country:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="new_country"/>
                            <input type="submit" value="save" class="gradient-button" id="submit9"/>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--//edit fields-->
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#field8" class="gradient-button edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </article>
    }
```

And the two controller actions:

```
public ActionResult MyProfile()
        {
            IAccountService accountSvc = GetService<IAccountService>();
            UserProfileServiceRequest request = new UserProfileServiceRequest();

            int userId = int.Parse(SessionMgr.GetInstance().GetSessionValue(SessionTypes.UserId).ToString());

            if (userId == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
            else
            {
                request.UserId = userId;
                UserProfileServiceResponse response = accountSvc.GetUserProfile(request);
                UserProfileViewModel model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<UserProfileViewModel>(response.UserProfile);

                ICommonService commonSvc = GetService<ICommonService>();
                GetCitiesServiceRequest citiesRequest = new GetCitiesServiceRequest { FirstAdminDivisionId = model.Address.City.FirstAdminDivision.FirstAdminDivisionId };
                KeyValuePairServiceResponse citiesResponse = commonSvc.GetCitiesForSelect(citiesRequest);
                model.CitySelectList = citiesResponse.KeyValuePairs.ToSelectList();

                List<RoleViewModel> roles = (List<RoleViewModel>)SessionMgr.GetInstance().GetSessionValue(SessionTypes.Roles);
                RoleViewModel consumerRole = roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Meaning.Equals(DataEnumerations.GetRoleMeaning(DataEnumerations.Role.Consumer)));

                if (consumerRole != null)
                {
                    GetConsumerTripsServiceRequest consumerTripsRequest = new GetConsumerTripsServiceRequest() { UserId = userId };
                    GetConsumerTripsServiceResponse consumerTripsResponse = commonSvc.GetConsumerTrips(consumerTripsRequest);
                    model.ConsumerTrips = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<TripViewModel>>(consumerTripsResponse.Trips);

                    GetUserReviewsServiceRequest userReviewsRequest = new GetUserReviewsServiceRequest() { UserId = userId };
                    GetUserReviewsServiceResponse userReviewsResponse = commonSvc.GetUserReviews(userReviewsRequest);
                    model.UserReviews = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<UserReviewViewModel>>(userReviewsResponse.UserReviews);
                }

                return View(model);
            }
        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyProfile(UserProfileViewModel model)
        {
            UpdateUserProfileServiceRequest request = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<UpdateUserProfileServiceRequest>(model);

            IAccountService accountSvc = GetService<IAccountService>();
            accountSvc.UpdateUserProfile(request);

            return RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "Account");

        }
```

The entire AddressViewModel class:

```
public class AddressViewModel
    {
        public Int32 AddressId { get; set; }
        public String Address1 { get; set; }
        public String Address2 { get; set; }
        public Int32 CityId { get; set; }
        public String PostalCode { get; set; }

        public CityViewModel City { get; set; }

    }
```

And the entire UserProfileViewModel:

```
public class UserProfileViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }
        public string HomePhone { get; set; }
        public int AddressId { get; set; }

        public AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }
        public MembershipViewModel Membership { get; set; }

        public List<TripViewModel> ConsumerTrips { get; set; }

        public List<UserReviewViewModel> UserReviews { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CitySelectList { get; set; }
        public int SelectedCityId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What you have shown works fine so I suspect you have omitted some important code (_"simplifying some for brevity"_)

Comment: The "brevity" was really just eliminating stuff that didn't pertain to the address (minus the code from the view itself).   I have added it all now so if you see anything I would greatly appreciate it.   It seems like it should work (I've used similar style before without issue).   I was hoping this was one of those stupid mistakes on my part that I just could see as I was so close to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form includes a hidden input for the property in addition to a dropdown list

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Address.CityId)
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Address.CityId, Model.CitySelectList, ..)
```

In effect you are passing back 2 values for the same property. The `DefaultModelBinder` reads the first (from the hidden input which is the original value) and sets the value of `Address.CityId`. Any subsequent values for the same property (from the dropdown list) are ignored.

Remove the hidden input and you model will be correctly bound with the selected value.